# Clicking out side select tag doesn't fire click event

Tags: javascript, firefox

I don't know if someone tackled with this issue before or not but it seems like a bug in firefox I can't find any way around it.

How to reproduce the bug :

1. Add an event listener on the document like click or mousedown
2. Then open any select tag on the document
3. Click outside the select tag

Expected:
To fire the event after clicking outside the select tag

I need to detect if the user clicked outside the select tag or not?

Answer (score 1):

When you *click* the `<select>` **HTML object** the browser (more specifically older versions of Firefox) adds a back-drop to the document and listens for a click within it in order to close the `<select>` after you perform a click outside of it (also thought as helpful for misclick prevention).

I just tested it on Firefox 53.0 and it did work fine (`onclick` triggered after `<select>` was open). On `mousedown` instantly blurs (sets the select out of focus) and closes it. Perhaps, you could share some of your code or a JSFiddle URL.

Simple **HTML** `<select>` with a `<button>` having an `onclick` *event* (Try with Firefox 53.0)

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button onclick="alert('Clicked')">M</button>
```

Comment: Please check the image that I have added above also check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLr9lMbhSug&feature=youtu.be I managed to hide the tooltip when you open the select tag, but to return the tooltip again you have to click twice outside of the select tag?

Comment: @AhmedSaber Video is unavailable to me.

Comment: Sorry my mistake please try again

Comment: Did you see the problem as if there is no back-drop when you hover over elements it works fine in chrome but not in Firefox

Comment: And it doesn't count the clicking outside the select tag as a click?

Comment: @AhmedSaber What version of Firefox are you utilising?

Comment: The Latest one in Ubuntu

Comment: @AhmedSaber Does the snippet reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

@Zerfir please try this code snippet on **Firefox 62.0 (64-bit)**

Open the select tag and hover over the button it shouldn't change the text as chrome does.

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button onmouseenter="this.innerHTML = Math.random();">M</button>
```